# User Exists and NotExists Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a query to check whether the user exists in mysql database or not? If the user exists in database then i will trigger to increase the count. I have to get count of users matching and also count of users not matching.

```
def ecount=0;
def necount=0;
function findUser(){
    def exists=User.executeQuery(SELECT * FROM USER WHERE name='test');  
    if (exists.size > 0) {
        ecount=ecount+1;
    }
    else {
        necount=necount+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Users matching what?  Users not matching what?

Answer (score 1):

You can use COUNT function to accomplish this.

```
def ecount=0;
def necount=0;
function findUser(){

 def exists=User.executeQuery(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_column)) FROM USER WHERE name='test');  
 if (exists.size > 0)
 {
   ecount=ecount+1;
 }
 else{
   necount=necount+1;
 }
}
```

Comment: i can use count but i want the count of distinct users.

Comment: Adding the `DISTINCT` keyword will get you the desired result. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's change it to this.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) FROM USER WHERE name='test'
```